# Calculated Field from Aggregated Fileds in Python Table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, crosstab, calculated-field

I am trying to reproduce a table like this in Python:

[image: Example Table]

I've tried the following:

```
df["cost_per_unit"] = df["cost"]/df["units"]

pd.pivot_table(df, index="bin", values=["cost","units", "cost_per_unit"], aggfunc='sum').
```

I've tried Googling and for whatever reason I can't seem to find anyone who does a calculated field with summated columns in a python pivot table.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 1) always try to provide your sample data as text. 2) what's wrong with `df["cost_per_unit"] = df["cost"]/df["units"]`?

Comment: Add the `cost_per_unit` to the pivot table rather than the dataframe.

Comment: Since you `pivot_table` in the end, I'm guessing the issue is that you have multiple observations per bin, and with your current implementation, `cost_per_unit` is the row-weighted average, and not the unit-weighted average that you would like. You should pivot to sum the cost and units per bin first, then calculate the average after the pivot.

Comment: `df2 = df.groupby('bin')['cost', 'units'].sum(); df2.assign(cost_per_unit=df2['cost'] / df2['units'])`

Comment: Alollz - I agree this is probably the best answer. Do I have to calculate the cost_per_unit by grouped bin and then append it to the table?

Comment: Alexander - that worked. Thank you!